# Excel, subtotal grouping, and determine existence of value

Tags: excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I have a worksheet; I have applied sub totals to this on ColA.  I'd like some way of highlighting the text of the value in ColA if a value is found in text of other columns, for example, given this:

```
+-------+------+
| ColA  | ColB |
+-------+------+
| Temp1 | val1 |
|       | val1 |
|       | null |
|       | val3 |
| Temp2 | val2 |
|       | null |
+-------+------+
```

I’d like to highlight Temp1 in red and Temp2 in green if the target value was val2

Is this possible with a bit of clever conditional formatting?

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible. I imagine you have something like the picture below:

[image]

By using custom formula:

[image]

You could achieve the green cell by using formula (notice I use "**;**" as delimiter):

```
=AND($E$2=B2;NOT(ISBLANK(A2))) - here we use "="
```

and the red one by:

```
=AND($E$2<>B2;NOT(ISBLANK(A2))) - here we use "<>"
```

So the formula checks for two conditions:

1. That the cell in B column is equal to the "target value", cell E2. -> `$E$2<>B2`
2. At the same row, the cell shouldn't be empty in Column A. -> `NOT(ISBLANK(A2))`